# Is it possible to run kubeadm init command to ignore generating certificates?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

When running `kubeadm init` command, by default the required certificates are generated under `/etc/kubernetes/pki location`.

Is there any option to run `kubeadm init` command to ignore generating certificates?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`--skip-phases`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#options) option to skip phases:

> --skip-phases
>   stringSlice List of phases to be skipped

**To skip the certificate generation:** 
`kubeadm init --skip-phases  certs`

This implies generating the certificates on your own. **You cannot use Kubernetes without a Certificate Authority (CA)**. Take a look on how [Manage TLS Certificates in a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/):

> Every Kubernetes cluster has a cluster root Certificate Authority
>   (CA). The CA is generally used by cluster components to validate the
>   API server’s certificate, by the API server to validate kubelet client
>   certificates, etc. To support this, the CA certificate bundle is
>   distributed to every node in the cluster and is distributed as a
>   secret attached to default service accounts.

And also [PKI Certificates and Requirements](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/certificates/):

> Kubernetes requires PKI certificates for authentication over TLS. If
>   you install Kubernetes with `kubeadm`, the certificates that your
>   cluster requires are automatically generated. You can also generate
>   your own certificates – for example, to keep your private keys more
>   secure by not storing them on the API server.

Comment: Using this option would expect the keys in /etc/kubernetes/pki/ location. Is there any option to ignore keys and installation to continue?

Comment: I wanted to skip the certificates itself

Comment: @SunilGajul you cannot waive the use of the certificate. Kubernetes Clusters, by design, requires root Certificate Authority (CA) for authentication over TLS. I updated the answer with the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes needs certificates. So it is only a choice about who will manage them (kubeadm or you).